# JBPM 6 - Creating a process with a "service task" like node, programmatically

Tags: java, drools, jbpm, bpmn

JBPM 6 user guide has listed [an example](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0/userguide/jBPMBPMN2.html#d0e3568) which allows a workflow process to be created programmatically using [Process API](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0/userguide/jBPMBPMN2.html#d0e3568).

I followed the example to create a service task (a task which has a class associated with, having the actual node execution code). Here's my code

```
//Headers
RuleFlowNodeContainerFactory rfncf = factory.name(process.getName()).version("1.0").packageName("test.package")
// Nodes
.startNode(1).name("Start").done();

rfncf.actionNode(1).name("sample-node-name")
     .action(new Action() {
            @Override
            public void execute(ProcessContext context) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("testing execution...");
            }
      })
.done();
```

In the above example, I am creating an action node and associating it with an anonymous inner class which implements `org.jbpm.process.instance.impl.Action`

When I run this code, I get the following exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jbpm.workflow.core.DroolsAction cannot be cast to org.jbpm.workflow.core.impl.DroolsConsequenceAction
  at org.jbpm.bpmn2.xml.XmlBPMNProcessDumper.visitEscalations(XmlBPMNProcessDumper.java:505)
  at org.jbpm.bpmn2.xml.XmlBPMNProcessDumper.visitProcess(XmlBPMNProcessDumper.java:143)
  at org.jbpm.bpmn2.xml.XmlBPMNProcessDumper.dump(XmlBPMNProcessDumper.java:98)
  at org.jbpm.bpmn2.xml.XmlBPMNProcessDumper.dump(XmlBPMNProcessDumper.java:89)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Searching on google yielded to an open bug on JBPM side (https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBPM-4378).

My question is, is there any alternative way of achieving the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can checkout a Process Fluent API [example](https://github.com/marianbuenosayres/jBPM6-Developer-Guide/blob/master/chapter-02/jBPM6-quickstart/src/test/java/com/wordpress/marianbuenosayres/quickstart/ProgrammedProcessExecutionTest.java) by Mariano De Maio, author of the jBPM6 Developer Guide. It's a little bit different approach (not using the RuleFlowNodeContainerFactory), but I can confirm that this one is working ;-)

Regards.

Comment: Amazing!.. so the problem was the way I was initializing `KieSession`, thanks a lot!